# Redactor - input elements in "insert link" dialog cannot get focus

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, redactor, redactor.js

I am trying to do something similar to what [this page](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/uidialog/) is doing.

The only difference is that the jQuery UI dialog I use is modal.

I tried editing the script in the page to make the jQuery UI dialog modal.

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog(
{
    modal: true, // added this line to make dialog modal
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    open: function(event, ui)
    {
        var textarea = $('<textarea style="height: 276px;">');
        $(textarea).redactor({
            focus: true,
            maxHeight: 300,
            initCallback: function()
            {
                this.code.set('<p>Lorem...</p>');
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

I then clicked on the **insert link** button(the 3rd button from the right in the toolbar). This shows another jQuery UI modal dialog with a form.

I noticed that I cannot get the focus of the text fields. I cannot type anything into them.

The code works fine if I don't make the the first dialog modal.

Any idea how to circumvent this?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem. This behavior is a result of jQuery UI handling `focusin.dialog` event on the document, and putting the focus back to the last  jQuery UI dialog in the stack (using selector `".ui-dialog:visible:last"`). I solved the problem by calling this code right after my modal dialog was created:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).unbind("focusin.dialog");
}, 100);
```

I used `setTimeout`, because jQuery UI also uses `setTimeout` to bind this event. I was able to fix it thanks to this answer: [jQuery UI Focus Stealing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665552/jquery-ui-focus-stealing). I also tried upgrading to jQuery UI 1.11.4 but that does not solve the problem.